# Console multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, console, stdout

I'm trying read stdout byte stream into MemoryStream. All's works properly until I run same code in parallel threads

```
        using (Process proc = new Process())
        {
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = eac3toFullPath;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "input.flac stdout.wav";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.Start();
            proc.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(mem);
            proc.WaitForExit();
            if (proc.ExitCode > 0)
            {
                throw new ConsoleAppException(proc);
            }
            mem.Position = 0;
        }
```

Problem occurs when first thread execute stdout copy to mem and in the same time second thread report ExitCode equal '1'

I started console app (CLI) from WinForm application so where is no console window allocated due to CreateNoWindow = true;
So I repeat myself. The code works well, the ExitCode of CLI process is always zero,
until I run the code above multiple times simultaneously.
StandardOutput is redirected as of matter of fact I can't see any friendly error output. I also tried RedirectStandardError and ErrorDataReceived event and BeginErrorReadLine() with no luck.

Comment: What problem does occur?

Comment: ExitCode should be always 0

Comment: Unless there was an error...these error code are readable by other programs like this one and its even available for batch files etc.